# How to modify a users firebase authentication token claims?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, immutability, firebase-admin

How can I update a users claims if the map returned is an immutable map?

This is example code from Firebase Auth docs on how to update claims:

```
    UserRecord user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        .getUserByEmail("user@admin.example.com");

    Map<String, Object> currentClaims = user.getCustomClaims(); //This returns an immutable map
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(currentClaims.get("admin"))) {
      currentClaims.put("level", 10); //This will throw an exception

      FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setCustomUserClaims(user.getUid(), currentClaims);
    }
```

[Firebase doc src](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

**Exception thrown**: UnsupportedOperationException: null
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.put(ImmutableMap.java:468)

[Firebase Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/7352a43a45bc81227354d06d1ce95713cf4408b8/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/auth/UserRecord.java#L239)

Comment: If you have problems with any Firebase documentation, you can use the "send feedback" button at the top of the page to explain what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I just finished doing that actually !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a copy of the map to make modifications to it using the [HashMap copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-).

```
Map<String, Object> immutableCustomClaims = user.getCustomClaims();
Map<String, Object> mutableCustomClaims = new HashMap<>(immutableCustomClaims)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that doc, it seems you can set claims by specifying a Map with the new values (ie. no need to specify values you are not modifying).